# Nested Function calling in Python

Tags: python, function, nested

```
def f1(): 
    X = 88
    def f2(): 
        print(X)
    return f2
action = f1() 
action()
```

Since `f1` is returning `f2` so it seems fine when I call f2 as `(f1())()`.

But when I call f2 directly as `f2()`, it gives error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between the function calling of `f2` using above 2 ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `f2` is *local* to the scope of function `f1`. Its name is only valid inside of that function because you defined it there. When you return `f2`, all you are doing is giving the rest of the program access to the function's properties, not to its *name*. The function `f1` returns something that prints 88 but does not expose the name `f2` to the outer scope.

Calling `f2` indirectly through `f1()()` or `action()` is perfectly valid because those names are defined in that outer scope. The name `f2` is not defined in the outer scope so calling it is a `NameError`.

Comment: Yes you are right. So when I call f1() it returns the pointer to f2() function. Which can be verified using :  >>> action
<function f1.<locals>.f2 at 0x10f28fc80>

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Just make sure you refer to the functions by their names only not by `func()` with parenthesis because this implies calling the function. Note how python stores them as `<function f1...>` which shows the name without `()`.